# Selenium + XPath: can 'following-sibling' be used for next element only?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selector

There is a simplified html table

```
<table>
    .....
    <tr/>
    <tr class="base"/>
    <tr class="check"/>
    <tr/>
    <tr class="base2"/>
    <tr class="check"/>
    .....
</table>
```

With selenium I have an element with class "base" found early.

```
var row = table.FindElement(By.ClassName("base"));
```

I need to get next row with class 'check' but only in case that it is present (otherwise an exception).

```
var nextRow = row.FindElement(By.XPath("following-sibling::tr[@class='check'][1]")
```

The problem is that this xpath gives me row with class 'check' after row with class 'base2' in case row after my class is absent.

Is it possible by 'following-sibling' to verify onle next element but not all of them?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but if you want the next `tr` sibling, and test if it does have the class you want, you can invert the predicates: `following-sibling::tr[1][@class='check']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this with CSS locator - `tr[class='base'] + tr[class='check']`

Will return next row if class '**check**' else nothing.

If you want the Xpath :

```
//tr[@class='base']/following-sibling::tr[1][@class='check']
```